# Can I plug an audio input device into my laptop and use it on a VM that runs on a different machine?

Tags: usb, audio, vmware, esxi

I am running ESXi on my Dell PowerEdge R710 (server) that sits upstairs in my office. I have created a [KXStudio](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=kxstudio) VM to run on ESXi host. I have a Dell laptop running Windows that connects through vSphere to the VMs.

I would like to plug my [Focusrite Scarlett 2i2](https://focusrite.com/usb-audio-interface/scarlett/scarlett-2i2) audio interface into the laptop (it is USB connected) when downstairs and use it to record audio that I will then edit/record/play with on the KXStudio VM.
I have been looking at USB pass-through settings, but they all talk about the USB device being connected to the ESXi host. I just want to know if it is even possible to work this way around?

I assume there could/will be data transfer rate issues as the audio from the 2i2 comes into the laptop through USB then has to travel over Ethernet up to the server. 
If I hit unusable lagging then that's another issue to overcome,
but I wonder if this is possible.

Comment: Yes, you _can_ pass a USB device to a VM using the vSphere Client, but with audio you will very probably have issues.

Comment: Since you’ve gotten minimal response in almost two days, I’ll make a comment: Based on my understanding of what you say, I believe that you should simply record the audio on the laptop and then send the audio files upstairs via a shared directory or filesystem, or email, or FTP, or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for the responses but I think the answer is no. After some further investigation I think the only way to utilise the server's power is to have a USB extension cable running directly from the host down to the input device.